# React Typescript assigning local json to useState

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a `data.json` file which I import by doing `import * as data from './data/data.json';`

in my `App` function, I am then doing `const [jobsObject, setJobsObject] = useState([]);`

To add it to my state, I am doing

```
useEffect(() => {
        setJobsObject(data);
    }, []);
```

I have seen the exact same code work in js. What I am getting is `Typescript Error`, which says `Argument of type '({ "id": number; "company": string; [a lot of lines describing content of this object ommited for brevity] is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Anybody has an idea of how to make it work?

Comment: We would need more info.

Comment: Does your code have any type definitions? That would help debug a type error.

Comment: @JakeWorth not really, no. I only really got started with that.

Comment: @Rajesh lmk what more you need to know

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix for this is asserting that whatever type `data` has, also is the expected one for `jobsObject`. So say that `const data: DataType` where

```
type DataType = {
  id: number;
  company: string;
};
```

then you want to assign

```
const [jobsObject, setJobsObject] = useState<DataType | undefined>(undefined);
```

I added `undefined` due to lack of further information and this is a reasonable pattern when you lack initiating value of your state variable. I noticed that you prefer defined it as an array, as `data` seems to be an object here, that's the primary issue that needs resolving. If you in fact have `data` as an array of objects with the type `DataType` you can simply extend the type definition by `DataType[]` making it an array.